# Get array from parse column into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, parse-platform

I've got several columns in my app where 1 column is of the type array. I want to get the items in that array in ONLY that row into my UITableView, but I have some problems as the numberOfRows only get 1 because there's only 1 row, but I want to count the array of that row instead of the rows themselves.

**How can I accomplish this with a PFQueryTableViewController?**

Here is some of my "experimenting code" with this:

```
#import "ReviewsViewController.h"
#import "MyManager.h"

@interface ReviewsViewController () {
// Declare variables
int totalCount;
int currentReview;
}

@end

@implementation ReviewsViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {

    // Setup currentReview
    currentReview = 0;

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Story";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell stlye
    self.textKey = @"objectId";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
}
return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query whereKey:@"Title" equalTo:[[MyManager sharedManager] selectedStory]];

return query;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Setup totalCount
totalCount = 1;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
// Set the delegate(s) and datasource
_reviewsTableView.delegate = self;
_reviewsTableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of objects in the section
NSArray *reviews = [[NSArray alloc] init];
for (PFObject *object in [self objects]){reviews = (NSArray *)[object objectForKey:@"Reviews"];}
totalCount = reviews.count;
NSLog(@"%@%d", @"count: ", totalCount);

return totalCount;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell
UILabel *reviewLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
NSArray *reviews = [[NSArray alloc] init];
for (PFObject *object in [self objects]){reviews = (NSArray *)[object objectForKey:@"Reviews"];}
reviewLabel.text = reviews[currentReview];
currentReview++; // Increase it for next time

return cell;
}

@end
```

**I have a feeling this code isn't of much use, but the goal is to get all the array items of 1 row into a UITableView - the question is, how?**

**UPDATE**

My "new" code gives me this error:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Here is the corresponding code:

```
#import "ReviewsViewController.h"
#import "MyManager.h"

@interface ReviewsViewController () {
// Declare variables
NSArray *myObjects;
}

@end

@implementation ReviewsViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Story";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell stlye
    self.textKey = @"objectId";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
}
return self;
}

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError*)error {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];
// Extract out the desired array and assign it to myObjects
myObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
for (PFObject *object in [self objects]){
    myObjects = (NSArray*)[object objectForKey:@"Reviews"];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query whereKey:@"Title" equalTo:[[MyManager sharedManager] selectedStory]];

return query;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
// Set the delegate(s) and datasource
_reviewsTableView.delegate = self;
_reviewsTableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return myObjects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell using myObjects
UILabel *reviewLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
reviewLabel.text = [myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

@end
```

**here you can see that both items in the array gets downloaded:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options, but this is the easiest in my opinion.

1) Create a new member variable, call it myObjects:

```
NSArray *myObjects;
```

2) Override objectsDidLoad:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError*)error {
   [super objectsDidLoad:error];
   // Extract out the desired array and assign it to myObjects
   myObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
   for (PFObject *object in [self objects]){
       myObjects = (NSArray*)[object objectForKey:@"Reviews"];
   }
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

3) Overload objectAtIndexPath:

```
- (PFObject*) objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName: @"Object"];
    [object setObject:[myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"string"];
    return object;
}
```

4) Use myObjects for numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return myObjects.count;
}
```

5) Use your custom object for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell using object
    UILabel *reviewLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    reviewLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"string"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've chosen the "Add exception breakpoint" but I just get to this screen - see my updated question

Comment: oh, I see at the top it says cellForRowAtIndexPath, perhaps the indexPath.row is the problem?

Comment: Any ideas? Problem is driving me crazy, last little piece of the puzzle ;) @Dehli